# Get DisplayName attribute from an MVC2 Model's Property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes

So, I've got a contact form in my MVC 2 application.

I'd like to programatically email all properties of my "`ContactModel`".

Here is what I'd like to do in psuedo-ish code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactModel model)
    if(!ModelState.IsValid){
        TempData["errorMessage"] = "You are a failure!";
        return View(model);
    }
    else{
        var htmlMessage = new StringBuilder("<table>");
        const string templateRow = "<tr><td>{0}: </td><td><strong>{1}</strong></td></tr>";

        /* ************************************************* */
        /* This is the part I need some serious help with... */
        /* ************************************************* */
        foreach(var property in someEnumerableObjectBasedOnMyModel){
            htmlMessage.AppendFormat(templateRow,
                // the display name for the property
                property.GetDisplayName(),
                // the value the user input for the property (HTMLEncoded)
                model[property.Key]
            );
        }
        /* ************************************************* */

        htmlMessage.Append("</table>");

        // send the message...
        SomeMagicalEmailer.Send("to@example.com", "from@example.com", "Subject of Message ", htmlMessage.ToString() );
        TempData["message"] = "You are awesome!";
        return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");
    }
}
```

*In case it matters...`ContactModel` sets up the `DisplayName` attributes like this:*

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string FirstName {get; set ;}
```

I'd like to keep this nice and DRY by not repeating the DisplayName names.

**Specifically, I'd like to enumerate over each property in my ContactModel, get its DisplayName, and get its submitted value.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use reflection over the object's properties and their custom attributes to get their name/value pairs.

```
foreach (var property in typeof(ContactModel).GetProperties())
{
     var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute),false)
                             .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>()
                             .FirstOrDefault();
     if (attribute != null)
     {
          var value = property.GetValue( model, null );
          var name = attribute.DisplayName;

          htmlMessage.AppendFormat( templateRow, name, value );
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 This works great. Is there any way to do it without reflection? The app will be running under MediumTrust. :-/

Comment: @David - not using the attributes directly.

Comment: for passers by: you can get the DisplayName via: `ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<ContactModel, string>( expression, new ViewDataDictionary<ContactModel>(model) ).DisplayName;`

Comment: @DavidMurdoch For this you need the model instance which you maybe have not but for the rest thats fine from you :)